# Any doc about express-helpers?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm new to Node and Express and I would like to make a form with [Express-Helpers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/native-view-helpers). Unfortunately, I don't understand how it works and I didn't find any simple doc (official or not) to follow or a tutorial...

If someone could help me to use it, I would really appreciate !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see, Express-helpers is just to help you build dynamic templates with [EJS](http://www.embeddedjs.com/). Seems rather unnecessary in my opinion. I would strongly suggest you get a frequently used template engine like JADE to start off with. They have most everything you would ever need and are easy to understand.

But since you asked, this template engine works like this...

```
// require your library 
var helper = require('native-view-helpers');
```

Now this helper object you have, has a lot of methods / functions that return strings based on their input. For example...

```
helper.form.begin(); // returns this string '<form action="" method="POST">'
```

This method/ function would be placed inside the EJS starting and ending bracket, like so...

```
<%- helper.form.begin(); %>
```

When rendered the through EJS, you would get

```
<form action="" method="POST">
```

This isn't the best example, but maybe it will help you understand whats going on.